# CNN with vector output and 2D image graph input (input is an array)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a CNN in Keras (Python 3.7) which ingests a 2D matrix input (much like a grayscale image) and outputs a 1 dimensional vector. So far I did manage to get results, but I am not sure if what I am doing is correct (or if my intuition is).

I input a 100x50 array into my convolutional layer. This 2D array holds the peak information at every position (ie. x axis pertains to the position, y-axis pertains to the frequency, and each cell gives the intensity). The 3D graph of this shows something akin to the one given in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/a-3D-and-b-top-view-Contour-plot-of-the-measured-Brillouin-gain-spectrum-BGS_fig8_321056806) link.

From the (all of the) literature I have read, I learned that CNN accepts image data--image is converted into pixel values and then repeatedly convolved and pooled to get the output. However, I am using a MatLab simulator to get my input data, and I have access to the raw 2D array containing information on the peak frequency at each point.

My intuition is this: if we normalize each cell and feed the information to the CNN, it will be as if I fed the normalized pixel values of the image to the CNN, since my raw 2D array also has height, width and depth=1, like an image.

Please enlighten me if my thinking is correct or wrong.

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

'''load sample input'''
BGS1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/strain1_input.csv")
BGS2 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/strain2_input.csv")
BGS3 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/strain3_input.csv")
BGS_ = np.array([BGS1, BGS2, BGS3]) #3x100x50 array

BGS_normalized = BGS_/np.amax(BGS_)

'''load sample output'''
BFS1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/strain1_output.csv")
BFS2 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/strain2_output.csv")
BFS3 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/strain3_output.csv")
BFS_ = np.array([BFS1, BFS2, BFS3]) #3x100
BFS_normalized = BFS/50 #since max value for each cell is 50

#after splitting data into training, validation and testing sets,
output_nodes = 100 
n_classes = 1
batch_size_ = 8 #so far, optimized for 8 batch size
epoch = 100 

input_layer = Input(shape=(45,300,1))
conv1 = Conv2D(16,3,padding="same",activation="relu", input_shape = 
(45,300,1))(input_layer)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),padding="same")(conv1)
flat = Flatten()(pool1)
hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(flat) #relu

batchnorm1 = BatchNormalization()(hidden1) 
output_layer = Dense(output_nodes*n_classes, activation="softmax")(batchnorm1) 
output_layer2 = Dense(output_nodes*n_classes, activation="relu")(output_layer) 
output_reshape = Reshape((output_nodes, n_classes))(output_layer2)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_reshape)

print(model.summary())
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', sample_weight_mode='temporal')

model.fit(train_X,train_label,batch_size=batch_size_,epochs=epoch)
predictions = model.predict(train_X)
```

Comment: it is not exactly clear which part of your reasoning you have doubts about. Is it the normlization? Is it the fact that your 2D matrix is not an actual image?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my question. The part where I am not clear about is the fact that my 2D matrix is not an actual image. And it works for my CNN, but all the literature I've read only mentions about CNN input as image data. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you did is exactly the strategy used to input non image data in to 2d convolutional layers. As long the model predicts correctly, what you did is correct. its just that CNN perform very poorly on non-image data or there might be chances to overfit. But then again, as long it performs correctly then its good.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! :)